# Fluent Nhibernate with SQL Compact: Schema Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, schema

Good evening people,

I have been using Fluent Nhibernate for a while, I've never really dug too deep into its functionality or the many ways it can be configured.  In every project I have used it in I have configure it as follows:

```
        if (nhConfig == null)
        {
            nhConfig = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
            nhConfig.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);

                                                                              // This obviously changes depending on what im trying to connect to
    nhConfig.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName);

                                                                              // Configuration is simply an implementation
                                                                              // of an IConfiguration interface 
            nhConfig.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, configuration.ConnectionString);


                                // In this instance, this resolves to
                                    // "NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect"
            nhConfig.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, configuration.Dialect.AssemblyQualifiedName);
            nhConfig.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true");

            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(nhConfig)
                                   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(configuration.MappingAssembly))
                                   .ExposeConfiguration(x => new SchemaUpdate(x).Execute(false, true))
                                   .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
```

Apologies for the poorly formatted code block...I can never figure out how to edit the code
once you paste it in without de-activating the code tags.

So as I say, in all of my other projects, this configuration code has worked fine.  The database has always been a SQLExpress database (2005 || 2008) and should the table not exist in the database for the specified entity, then it is automatically created.

However, this time an SQL Compact database is required. I have created this database simply by adding a new Database item to my assembly (TestingDB.sdf) and have actually created a "Customer" table.

Now I have the following unit test:

```
[Test]
    public void Function_CanCreateDomainObject()
    {
        // Create a fake entity that is mapped
        Customer fakeCustomer = new Customer();
        fakeCustomer.Name = "Function_CanCreateDomainObject";
        fakeCustomer.Birthday = DateTime.Now;

        // Get a DAO for communication
        IBaseDAO<Customer> customerDao = Container.RequestForType <IBaseDAO<Customer>>();

        // Persist the domiain object
        customerDao.Create(fakeCustomer);

        // Retrieve it in a new instance
        Customer retrievedCustomer = customerDao.Read(fakeCustomer.Id);

        // Compare values for equality
        Assert.That(retrievedCustomer.Id.Equals(fakeCustomer.Id),
            "Retrieved entity with Name: " + retrievedCustomer.Name + "(" + retrievedCustomer.Id + ")" +
            "does not match with original entity with Name: " + fakeCustomer.Name + "(" + fakeCustomer.Id + ")");
    }
```

Regardless of the poorly designed 'unit test' the test falls over with the following error:

```
ERROR [TestRunnerThread] SchemaUpdate [(null)]- could not complete schema update 
       System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
```

Yes, I have all the required assemblies from the SQL Compact folder on my C:\ and in fact here is the strange part, in trying to find the source of this error, I of course debugged the unit test and stepped through the procedure line-by-line.  On two occasions, the test has passed and the 'fakeCustomer' entity is persisted correctly in my database, however, 99% of the time, it will fail with the aforementioned error.  The test has passed both when stepping through the test line-by-line and when simply running it from the Nunit GUI.

So, it seems like NHibernate can not imply the table structure of a SQL Compact database on its own, which is strange because I am using the ClassMap technique of FNHibernate and you'd think this would be sufficient enough to imply a table schema....every time the test is run.

Any help of guidance greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: please post the entire stack trace